# use variable as a method in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to dynamically call methods by a variable name in typescript, as shown in the following example.

```
function callMethod(_class, method: string){
  let classObj = new _class();
  return classObj[method]()
}
```

the previous code snippet has no real benefits, but it can obviously explain the idea with a minimal code.

however, if you enabled the option `noImplicitAny` in tsconfig.json, you have to add a type annotation

```
return classObj[method as keyof typeof classObj]()
```

Theoretically, it works fine in Js, but ts complains that not all constituents are callable, and shows this error:

```
This expression is not callable.
  Not all constituents of type ... are callable.
```

how can I dynamically call a method in typescript?

Comment: Maybe it is possible, but then you'd have to make sure the code is not minified. You could also create a record of functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the method, the class, and the static part of the class all generic, you can do something like this:

```
function callMethod<
  M extends PropertyKey,
  C extends {[K in M]: () => any},
  T extends {new(): C}
>(_class: T, method: M): ReturnType<InstanceType<T>[M]> {
  const classObj = new _class();

  return classObj[method]() 
}

class Test {
    someMethod(): number { return 8}
}

const t1 = callMethod(Test, 'someMethod') // Inferred type: number.

const t2: string = callMethod(Test, 'someMethod')
// ERROR: .. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.

const t3 = callMethod(Test, 'noMethod')
// ERROR: .. Property 'noMethod' is missing in type 'Test' but required in
//        type '{ noMethod: () => unknown; }'.
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQWQKZQBZwAmAPAFCKKaLYAeU2YhAzogAoBOcADtu1AJ4BpbPwA05RAGFqdBs0QBvANqDEMJJgC6ALkQAKAJSIAvAD5EKMPwC+4igBUZ9RiwVhsAd0O7J10qb0AfQg0FCYmXXtRRABbXAJCXUwDXQAlXBB2MHt+HmIASTAmKEsIbBy8+1MlLXMFCQgEYuRQ8IB5ACMAKxNEdw9EYNamQwBuUgl2DKyWsKZOrqU4-CJNQ0RSP1IQucR7bGb6igomODicFcJvPpAYjt5FRCmoTKQADj8txqKoRCgARl6qAwFwSen2xWiAHJTud4kQoUYAPRIxCFYC8KaEP65bC6MC3e7sAB0E2+zSgACZdMV2OoAOZA9BYeFXCFQaGw7CghEGUgoxAAUVSqTaqV0xOJe1xiChBLuvChahYYDgvzmMHpYBQHTQ2D+cBxPFltIZUNJ2yavygAGYmSDWeCDhzZaqeYREfzUcLReLEJK2JweHx+K64O6lTAWDEo0wGWokAJjVD2UqOiBflMAI4gGBYhNG-VQhR9cOs3TrMyIcAAa1VHjAo0Q1nNpCAA)

Inside `callMethod` the return type of `method` will be `any`, but typing this to a fourth type parameter and getting it to agree with `ReturnType<InstanceType<T>[M]>` seems tricky (and might not be possible). As long as you directly return the result of the method call, this shouldn't be too much of an issue though.

Comment: Maybe even a fourth parameter for the return type ([playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQWQKZQBZwAmAPAFCKKaLYAeU2YhAzogAoBOcADtu1AJ4BpbPwA05RACVxFAMLU6DZogDeAbUGIYSTAF0AXIgAUASkQBeAHxSAvjMQAVBfUYsVYbAHdTh2TdKWRgD6EGgoTEyGDqKIALa4BISGmCaGkqoSaLjIYREA8gBGAFYWiB6eiCG5TKYA3BLsuCDsSKHhTIVFavH4RLqmpP6kbRGO2ExQGRQUTHDxOL2EPmUgsQW8qoiNUM1IAIyI-tOIcPi8C4nLE+zaAOab27uIAOTPh4OkwwgTiDSGYKt1uxSqgMBciEYHOMoDFnrN5gkiM8TF8wD9+P9ARtzMh0FhEUsoRNYac8OcCcjSEA))?

Comment: @Bergi Was just looking into that, but the return type of `callMethod` remains `unknown`.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed :-/ But it's better than `any`, and complains if you require some specific return type but the method doesn't satisfy it. Might make a good next question how to do that properly…

Comment: @Bergi It's better than any, indeed. I'm still looking at some other options but if they don't work I'll just add in the extra parameter.

Comment: @Bergi Found a solution that at least infers the correct return type, though internally it will still be any.